# Problema con emotion (styled components) en Gatsby

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, componentes

Utilizo styled component en gatsby pero ahora han actualizado emotion y me tira error. Lo instalo de esta manera en mi proyecto

```
npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled gatsby-plugin-emotion
```

Después, por ejemplo en el componente Header quiero hacer uso de emotion de la siguiente manera

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import Navegacion from './navegacion';
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header
      css={css`
        background-color: #0d283b;
        padding: 1rem;
      `}
    >
      <div
        css={css`
          max-width: 120rem;
          margin: 0 auto;
          text-align: center;
          @media (min-width: 768px) {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
          }
        `}
      >
        <Navegacion />
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
 
export default Header;
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
WebpackError: The `@emotion/core` package has been renamed to `@emotion/react`. Please import it like this `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'`.
```

Ahora bien, solamente extraje jsx de @emotion/react solamente porque lo dice la documentacion, no lo necesito ni se para que sirve. Pero igual me sigue dando error ya he intando mil formas y no entiendo que puede ser.

Mi package.json tengo /react y /core porque no funcionaba con el /react solo, me pedía descargar el /core aunque teóricamente no debería funcionar mas porque lo han actualizado, creo.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.26.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^4.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.6.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.8.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0"
  },
```

Mi gatsby-config:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    // {
    //   resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
    //   options: {
    //     name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
    //     short_name: `starter`,
    //     start_url: `/`,
    //     background_color: `#663399`,
    //     theme_color: `#663399`,
    //     display: `minimal-ui`,
    //     icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
    //   },
    // },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

AYUDA!!

Answer (score 0):

Hola tuve el mismo problema y lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera, solo debes de instalar lo siguiente:

```
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

El plugin lo instalaste bien y lo estas mandando a llamar bien en tu gatsby-config,
el @emotion/core no lo necesitas, cuando lo vayas a importar en el componente que lo necesites en vez de poner `import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react';` usa `import {} from '@emotion/react'` en mi caso usé `import {Global, css} from '@emotion/react';` Ya cuando lo mandes a llamar en tu componente sería algo así para tener un css mas lineal:

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Global 
        styles={css`
          body{
            background-color: red;
          }
        `}
      />
    </>
  );
}
 
export default Layout;
```

Espero y te sirva, saludos

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para ayudarme. Resulta que mi problema era que habian actualizado emotion pero no el plugin de Gatsby!